# Почему не изменяется словарь в массиве?

Tags: python

```
a = [{'name': '127345', 'digit': 12345}, {'name': '134256547', 'digit': 12355545}]
e = []

for i in a:
    i['name'].replace('7', '9')
    e.append(i)
print(e)
```

Поменял 7 на 9, а изменения не сохраняются, в новый список сохраняется тоже самое, как мне сохранить в переменной изменения которые проделаны в цикле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо сохранить результат замены:

```
a = [{'name': '127345', 'digit': 12345}, {'name': '134256547', 'digit': 12355545}]
e = []

for i in a:
    new_val = i.copy()
    new_val['name'] = new_val['name'].replace('7', '9')
    e.append(new_val)
print(e)
```

Обратите внимание на `i.copy()`, если вы напишите так,

```
a = [{'name': '127345', 'digit': 12345}, {'name': '134256547', 'digit': 12355545}]
e = []

for i in a:
    i['name'] = i['name'].replace('7', '9')
    e.append(i)
print(e)
print(a)
```

то у вас изменятся словари и в списке a
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]